# Given a solution of a differential equation, determine the differential eqution itself

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry if my layout is bad, I'm new.
So this question was asked a couple of years ago on an exam about differential-equations.
Suppose you have a third order differential-equation with the following general solution:

$c_1J_2+c_2Y_2+\frac {c_3}{x^2}$

where $J_2$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and $Y_2$ one of the second kind, then what is the differential-equation?
I really don't know how to start, I'm guessing order reduction has something to do with it, but can someone give me a hint to start.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Oops, sorry, now it's there :)

Comment: what differential equation/s do $J_2, Y_2$ solve? i know you said bessel, but can you write it out?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function $Y_2$ appears when the alpha is a natural number and you need to find a second solution for the differential-equation with order reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that $c_1J_2+c_2Y_2$ is the solution of the Bessel equation of the first kind :
$$x^2y''+x y'+(x^2-4)y=0$$
The solution of $$x^2y''+x y'+(x^2-4)y=f(x)$$
is on the form $y=c_1J_2+c_2Y_2+y_p(x)$ where $y_p(x)$ is a particular solution.

In the present case, $y_p(x)=c_3/x^2$. Hense :
$$x^2y_p''+x y_p'+(x^2-4)y_p=f(x)$$
Now, you can find $f(x)$

I change the notation to $y_p$ in order to avoid a confusion with the Bessel $Y_2$

Comment: Thank you very much, if I didn't calculate anything wrong, this should be the solution $f(x)=−12c_3/x_2+c_3.$

Comment: That is not what I found.

Comment: Yeah I made a sign-error, now I have $c_3=f(x)$, I am just filling $y_p$ in in the differential-equation, is that right, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, $f(x)=c_3$

Comment: What do you mean << I am just filling $y_p$ is in the differential-equation >> ? In fact, $y_p(x)=c_3/x^2$ is a particular solution of the differential equation. It is not << in the equation >>.

Comment: Oh, yes I know that, I know what particular solution is. It's just, the way I found it is by doing the following:
Derive $\frac{c_3}{x^2}$ twice and multiply it by $x^2$ plus the first derivative multiplied by $x$ and so on..

Comment: Very well. Sorry for the misunderstanding.